# ¿Como estan definido el tiempo el las graficas de nvd3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo varias graficas de nvd3, y leyendo me he enterado que para colocar las tiempo en la columna x se debe pasar a tiempo unix, pero estos datos

```
//Siendo el primer dato el tiempo y el segundo el valor]
values: [[1083297600000, -2.974623048543], [1085976000000, -1.7740300785979], [1088568000000, 4.4681318138177], [1091246400000, 7.0242541001353], [1093924800000, 7.5709603667586], [1096516800000, 20.612245065736], [1099195200000, 21.698065237316], [1101790800000, 40.501189458018], [1104469200000, 50.464679413194], [1107147600000, 48.917421973355], [1109566800000, 63.750936549160], [1112245200000, 59.072499126460], [1114833600000, 43.373158880492], [1117512000000, 54.490918947556], [1120104000000, 56.661178852079], [1122782400000, 73.450103545496], [1125460800000, 71.714526354907], [1128052800000, 85.221664349607], [1130734800000, 77.769261392481], [1133326800000, 95.966528716500], [1136005200000, 107.59132116397], [1138683600000, 127.25740096723], [1141102800000, 122.13917498830], [1143781200000, 126.53657279774], [1146369600000, 132.39300992970], [1149048000000, 120.11238242904], [1151640000000, 118.41408917750], [1154318400000, 107.92918924621], [1156996800000, 110.28057249569], [1159588800000, 117.20485334692], [1162270800000, 141.33556756948], [1164862800000, 159.59452727893], [1167541200000, 167.09801853304], [1170219600000, 185.46849659215], [1172638800000, 184.82474099990], [1175313600000, 195.63155213887], [1177905600000, 207.40597044171], [1180584000000, 230.55966698196], [1183176000000, 239.55649035292], [1185854400000, 241.35915085208], [1188532800000, 239.89428956243], [1191124800000, 260.47781917715], [1193803200000, 276.39457482225], [1196398800000, 258.66530682672], [1199077200000, 250.98846121893], [1201755600000, 226.89902618127], [1204261200000, 227.29009273807], [1206936000000, 218.66476654350], [1209528000000, 232.46605902918], [1212206400000, 253.25667081117], [1214798400000, 235.82505363925], [1217476800000, 229.70112774254], [1220155200000, 225.18472705952], [1222747200000, 189.13661746552], [1225425600000, 149.46533007301], [1228021200000, 131.00340772114], [1230699600000, 135.18341728866], [1233378000000, 109.15296887173], [1235797200000, 84.614772549760], [1238472000000, 100.60810015326], [1241064000000, 141.50134895610], [1243742400000, 142.50405083675], [1246334400000, 139.81192372672], [1249012800000, 177.78205544583], [1251691200000, 194.73691933074], [1254283200000, 209.00838460225], [1256961600000, 198.19855877420], [1259557200000, 222.37102417812], [1262235600000, 234.24581081250], [1264914000000, 228.26087689346], [1267333200000, 248.81895126250], [1270008000000, 270.57301075186], [1272600000000, 292.64604322550], [1275278400000, 265.94088520518], [1277870400000, 237.82887467569], [1280548800000, 265.55973314204], [1283227200000, 248.30877330928], [1285819200000, 278.14870066912], [1288497600000, 292.69260960288], [1291093200000, 300.84263809599], [1293771600000, 326.17253914628], [1296450000000, 337.69335966505], [1298869200000, 339.73260965121], [1301544000000, 346.87865120765], [1304136000000, 347.92991526628], [1306814400000, 342.04627502669], [1309406400000, 333.45386231233], [1312084800000, 323.15034181243], [1314763200000, 295.66126882331], [1317355200000, 251.48014579253], [1320033600000, 295.15424257905], [1322629200000, 294.54766764397], [1325307600000, 295.72906119051], [1327986000000, 325.73351347613], [1330491600000, 340.16106061186], [1333166400000, 345.15514071490], [1335758400000, 337.10259395679], [1338436800000, 318.68216333837], [1341028800000, 317.03683945246], [1343707200000, 318.53549659997], [1346385600000, 332.85381464104], [1348977600000, 337.36534373477], [1351656000000, 350.27872156161], [1354251600000, 349.45128876100]],
```

Pero estos datos 1351656000000 o no son unix, no se que formato sea

he usado todos los convertirdores del formato dd-mm-yyyy a unix, y el resultado me da una fecha totalmente diferente a la que muestra las graficas

Alguien puede ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deben ser el tiempo transcurrido en milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970.

Para convertirlo a la fecha puedes hacerlo así:

```js
var date = new Date(1083297600000);
alert(date);
```

Comment: Eres Grande, Gracias ese era mi error y era obvio, no se como no me di cuenta antes,  se puede hacer así de igual forma

`date_Value = new Date('2012.08.'+i+'').getTime();`

gracias nuevamente